# how can I display a list on console using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015, i'm practicing C#.
How can I display a list on the console after the user enters the information?
I might be doing it wrong, I am still learning C#. Once I all info i entered how do i get the console to display the info collected? I have a set number for the gross income, I don't know how to change it so that the user can enter any number and calculate it yet, (still working on it) any suggestions, links, videos are welcome. I was looking at some pluralsight tutorials but do not seem to show how to do this.

```
//My first program 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticeProgram
{
   public class Program
   {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> myContacts = new List<Person>();

        //You could loop to collect developers data
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome developer, enter your name to continue");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);

            Console.WriteLine("enter your address");
            string address = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(address);

            Console.WriteLine("enter your monthly income");
            double GrossMonthlyPay = 10000;
            Console.WriteLine(GrossMonthlyPay);

            Console.WriteLine("your tax deduction set at 7% is ");
            double taxes = (0.07);
            Console.WriteLine(taxes = GrossMonthlyPay * taxes);

            Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            myContacts.Add(new Person(name, address, GrossMonthlyPay, taxes));
        }

    }
}

internal class Person
{
    private string address;
    private double grossMonthlyPay;
    private string name;
    private double taxes;

    public Person(string name, string address, double grossMonthlyPay, double taxes)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.grossMonthlyPay = grossMonthlyPay;
        this.taxes = taxes;
    }

    internal static Person ReadFromCSV(string line)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal void SerializeToCSV(string v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to display a collection, you need to loop through them with **`foreach`** or **`for loop`**

```
foreach (Person element in myContacts)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(element.name);
    ....
    etc
}
```

Comment: so where would this foreach should go? and would this print out like a list of all data at the end of the program? I know with Java you can print out the data like in a table format. Can this be done with C#?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you override your ToString() method of Person.  That way anywhere you want to display the string representation of Person, it'll display the same thing:

```
internal class Person
{
    private string address;
    private double grossMonthlyPay;
    private string name;
    private double taxes;

    public Person(string name, string address, double grossMonthlyPay, double taxes)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.grossMonthlyPay = grossMonthlyPay;
        this.taxes = taxes;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name=" + this.name + ",Address =" + this.address + " Monthly Pay=" + this.grossMonthlyPay + " Taxes=" + this.taxes.ToString();
    }

    internal static Person ReadFromCSV(string line)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal void SerializeToCSV(string v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ctznkane525 that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

As for getting the Gross Monthly Pay from user, I believe you can use the same method as how u get the names.

```
string GrossMonthlyPayInput = Console.ReadLine();
double GrossMonthlyPay = 0;
```

And most probably you want to make sure that only numbers are used so you can use parse, following this link: [Float/Double type input validation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521306/float-double-type-input-validation-in-c-sharp) or from here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/84990ad2-5046-472b-b103-f862bfcd5dbc/how-to-check-string-is-number-or-not-in-c?forum=winforms

So something like:

```
if (double.TryParse(GrossMonthlyPayInput, out j))
    GrossMonthlyPay = double.Parse(GrossMonthlyPayInput);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Please Input numbers only");
```

I haven't tried this code also and I might not be answering your question too well if I misunderstood your question so I apologize first because I am also new to C#.